Create multiple threads from a single thread variable
I've been learning about threads lately and I'm confused about something. I thought we can only create one thread from a thread variable and that thread can only execute one job, but in the code below, I create four threads from a global thread variable and they print at the same time. What I mean by 'at the same time' is that all functions run without waiting for the previous one to complete.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t thread;

void *func4() {

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        printf("/\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void *func3() {

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func4, NULL);

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        printf("*\n");
        sleep(1);
    }

    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
}

void *func2() {

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func3, NULL);

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        printf("-\n");
        sleep(1);
    }

    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
}

void *func1() {

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func2, NULL);

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        printf("+\n");
        sleep(1);
    }

    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
}

int main() {

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    return 0;
}


Is this a concept or do I know or use something wrong?

You should check the return values of your function calls for errors. Bet most of those pthread_join()s will have one.

The thread function take a void * argument

You do not create a pthread “from” a thread variable. You call pthread_create to create a thread, and you tell it where to put the thread ID.
What you have done is create four threads and told pthread_create to put the thread IDs in the same place. This results in multiple attempts to store thread ID values in one object. At best, that leaves you with one valid thread ID in the object, so you have lost the other values, and the pthread_join calls will not receive the proper IDs. (At worst, the write attempts can conflict with each other and corrupt the object, leaving no valid ID in it, but this is somewhat unlikely in modern circumstances.)

We can fix this either by (1) Having a unique global pthread_t variable for each usage, or (2) a global array of pthread_t or (3) move pthread_t thread; to function scope.
